# Fedora Core 6: Can't seem to install yum

Tags: linux, yum

I am a Linux noob, so I try to get apache and PHP running for my websites, then I leave my Linux server alone, and it just works, no complaints.

However, this time, I am working with a Network Solutions VPS, and it has no utilites pre-installed like yum. I'm trying to install these utilities, but the problem seems to be that all the instructions are for different distributions of linux or for a different version of FC. The latest instruction, on http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-install-yum-problems-installing-on-linux-redhat-fedora-commands-t471.html - leads to this error.

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.4.3 (#1, Oct  1 2006, 17:59:36) 
[GCC 4.1.1 20060928 (Red Hat 4.1.1-28)]
```

Everything was good till I got to the line ./configure - apparently the newer version of yum doesn't have this directory??

Is installing a program completely different for every version? I'm actually just trying to install APC for PHP caching, but everything I've read says yum is best for this...

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Update: I'm looking through my directories, and I see /yum.repos.d, how can I install it from there?**

**Crap readme says run "make install" if you're a masochist, which is exactly what I did :(
What does make install do in this case...**

Comment: Why did you accept a VM running an obsolete OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be installing it from an RPM. Though - it's very odd for an FC6 machine to not have yum installed by default.

Here are the FC6 RPMs - you could try downloading yum and it's dependencies and installing with rpm -Uvh *.rpm

http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/updates/6/i386/
http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/6/i386/os/Fedora/RPMS/

Comment: That FC 6 repository page was really what I needed... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the instructions you posted, FC6 requires yum version 3.0.1

Is this the version you downloaded? If you just copied and pasted from the code boxes then you probably got the wrong version of yum.

Try substituting the following lines for the ones in the directions.

```
wget http://linux.duke.edu/projects/yum/download/3.0/yum-3.0.1.tar.gz
tar -xvzf yum-3.0.1.tar.gz
cd yum-3.0.1
```

There is also no configure script in that folder. So ignore the ./configure line and jump straight to make.

According to the INSTALL file in there this isn't the best way to get yum working, so good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I should have included that... I changed to V3.0.1 - which is why the ./configure command didn't do anything... I proceeded to enter command make install...readme says only do that if you're a masochist? What's painful?

Comment: Running make install should put everything in its place in the filesystem. 

The only downside to this that I know of is that it will not be handled by package management. Among other things, this means if you wanted to remove it you would have to go back into the yum-3.0.1 directory and run make uninstall. 

There may be other consequences. For example, if something checks to see if you have yum installed through the package manager, it will look as if it isn't installed. AFAIK, this is why it is suggessted that you install from a rpm.

Comment: Sorry, but most of that was Greek to me. I grew up in a microsoft environment, which apparently means I know nothing. I am a junior programmer with a degree in management information systems, yet I can't install a program on Linux. I can even see the files on the server but still I am powerless. I don't know if I should mail my diploma back or chuck this Linux server out the window..

Comment: You didn't think that your degree would actually teach you anything *practical*, did you?